# Combine hover info with onclick info in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to do some complex thing. I wonna have:

1. popup with a name of a feature on mouse hover,
2. popup with more complex info ( name, foto, etc.) after mouseclick on the same feature - the same layer.

It is possible to have those two things at the same time??

Answer (score 1):

Think so.

OpenLayers.Handler.Feature - http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Feature-js.html#OpenLayers.Handler.Feature.touchstart

Just check if the feature is selected (onClick / selected) for the 2. popup and for the first one if its touched.

I'm not sure if it will work cross layer - don't think so though.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. Well I'm just a beginner with javascript. Can U help me with some piece of code, handled this issue?

Comment: Would like to help you, but have not a single running WebServer at the moment in my dev env. just trying to migrate to ngineX. Sorry. :( -- But check this: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/ -- Did help me a few times!